# Manga where the main character can stockpile skill effects used against him

Tags: story-identification, manga

I can't for the life of me remember the name of this manga where the main character can stockpile skill effects used against him?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Answer (score 0):

Is it *Starting From The Limit Level 1*?

There are a lot of manga with skill absorption. See the [list on r/Isekai](https://www.reddit.com/r/Isekai/wiki/index/specific_job_or_skill_set/power_absorption/).

There are also manga where the main character gains skills by eating/walking, or killing people like *Nito's Lazy Foreign World Syndrome*.

It could also be *I'm the Only One with a Failure of a Skill in Another World's Summoning Rebellion — Until the Weakest Skill [Absorption] Swallows Everything*